# Recursive mapped type causes "circularly references itself in mapped type" to be shown

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

I'm trying to make a type that will validate some object that we typically receive from an API.
However, when I have a property that recursively references itself, I get this error: `Type of property 'children' circularly references itself in mapped type`

How do I allow the recursive mapped type to handle recursive fields?

I want to use a mapped recursive type like this:

```js
type StandardType<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends number 
    | string 
    | boolean 
    | Array<number> 
    | Array<string> 
    | Array<boolean> 
    | StandardType<T[K]> 
    | Array<StandardType<T[K]>> 
    | null 
        ? T[K] 
        : never;
}
```

However, when making a generic class that has the generic type extend `StandardType`, like below:

```js
interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    children: Array<Person>;
}

class TestClass<T extends StandardType<T>> {
    constructor( person: T ) {}
}

const test: TestClass<Person> = new TestClass( {
    name: "one",
    age: 30,
    children: [
        {
            name: "child",
            age: 5,
            children: [],
        }
    ]
} );
```

Comment: What's the point of `JsonType<T>`? If it's to validate JSON, it doesn't work: `JsonType<{x(): void; y: Date}>` is `{x: ()=>void; y: Date}`. Could you [edit] to either fix the example, or change it to something completely arbitrary (and without the misleading name) so we're not distracted by things you're not asking about? TS doesn't support all circular constraints, see [ms/TS#51011](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51011)). They are often rewritable to forms the compiler accepts, but I don't want to spend effort on that if it's not a good [mre] to begin with.

Comment: My bad, I've updated the example to make it more generic.

Comment: All you did was change the name; if it's not supposed to do anything in particular you can surely reduce it to a [mre].  For example, [this version](https://tsplay.dev/WkErLN) is simpler and has the same problem.  But now it's obvious that the definition is *weird*; why would you want to *check* `T[K] extends StandardType<T[K]>>` in its own definition instead of just *transforming* the property to `StandardType<T[K]>`?  And here's where having some use case would be useful, because it would give others some idea for how to fix it without defeating its purpose. So, what's the purpose?